# Trying to perform an action like 'Unwrap' in TextMate

Tags: python, csv

I am processing a csv file which has CRLF in some of the text in my text file. It will make processing of the text file easier if I can get rid of the unwanted CRLF and keep the legit ones.

TextMate has a feature that does exactly what I'm looking for but I'm unable to replicate it using python.

I am new to python but from the self study I've done so far I can see it is really easy and powerful so I anticipate there may be an existing library or function which will allow me to do this easily. I would appreciate it if somebody can point me in the right direction.

Otherwise I will have to script the logic.

Thanks

**Sample of unprocessed text file:**
[image: Unprocessed file]

**Sample of the same text file with Unwrap applied:**
[image: Processed file]

The file is easier to read once it has been processed and it also becomes clear how the export file is structured i.e.: Each line ends with the same text it started with (Structure, Selection, Key Figures, Selection, Key Figures etc)

```html
            Free Characteristics                                                                Free Characteristics
            Rows                                                                Rows
            Columns                                                             Columns

                Structure                                                   Key Figures     Structure

                    Selection                                               Actual 
LY
&ZQRT_1T&   Column_001  Selection

                        Key Figures                                         Actual 
LY
&ZQRT_1T&   1KYFNM  Key Figures

                    Selection                                               Profit &0T_VERS& 
CY
&ZQRT_1T&   Column_003  Selection

                        Key Figures                                         Profit &0T_VERS& 
CY
&ZQRT_1T&   1KYFNM  Key Figures

                            Calculated KF                                       FIN Forecast
REV (NODIM) ZCKF_FFC_REV_NODIM  Calculated KF

                                Formula                                 FIN Forecast
REV (NODIM) ZCKF_FFC_REV_NODIM  Formula
```

Comment: Provide the input as a text, and also whatever you have attempted in code!

Comment: So I am starting out in python but have coding experience. I just want the name of a function or regex I can use to accomplish what I need. I'm not looking for someone to do the code for me. Code snippet of the CSV added. Thanks

Comment: This is not a CSV file. Python is great at processing text files, yet it is a programming language. That means that to process your file, you will have to write a script, not to just call a *magic* word

Comment: Hi Serge, It is a tab separated CSV file. The challenge is the CRLF in some of the values. Thanks for the information though - it is just what I needed - either the name of an existing function or confirmation that I will have to code the functionality.